# Change indentation settings in VIM with Janus

Tags: vim, janus

I'm trying to change the indentation settings on my vim config, which is currently set to 2 spaces. But neither changing the vimrc.old nor vimrc.after manually nor using the `echo 'setting' >> ~/.vimrc.after` way is changing the setting. How can I change my indentation settings with Janus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop Janus and use a regular `~/.vimrc`.

Alternatively, you could type `:verbose set {setting}` to see where `{setting}` is set. The "problem", here, is that Vim may use a bunch of settings for indentation: try the code above with:

```
tabstop
softtabstop
shiftwidth
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't have to drop Janus. I really like janus myself (for the color theme).

Just create a file `~/.vimrc.after`

within the file, set tab to 4 spaces `set tabstop=4`

Then janus will load the .vimrc.after file after janus

Comment: what do you mean the `visual`?

Comment: I just like syntax color janus provide, the normal syntax color from vim is not as pleasing.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found was to create a folder in the ~/.janus folder (let's call it mysettings)

In *~/.janus/mysettings/after/ftplugin/* create a file with the name of your file-type you wish to change the indent for. For cpp it would be *cpp.vim*

Then inside this file set the indent style you wish to use, in my case:

```
setlocal noexpandtab
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal textwidth=0
```

Then in your *.vimrc.after* put a line

```
filetype plugin indent on
```